# Possible to Preserve Service Variables in Angular JS w/ UI-Router?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

As the title says, is it possible to preserve a variable stored in a service on page refresh? I am assuming the answer is "No, use local storage or server-side," but I just wanted a confirmation.

As an example:

```
angular.module('app').service('testService', function() {
    var isTrue = undefined;
    var service = {
        setIsTrue: function (bool) {
            isTrue = bool;
        }, getisTrue : function () {
            return isTrue ;
        }
    };
    return service;
};
```

Is my assumption that any time the user refreshes the page (in their browser, not $state.reload()), the var "isTrue" will be reset to undefined?

Comment: w/ page refreshes, you need to store your variable outside of the app itself

Comment: You're right. You need to store information in a database, cookie, local storage etc. Once an app is refreshed, any data that is client side is lost.